# Decrypt files moved to USB drive and back

Tags: windows, windows-10, encryption

I'm on a Win10 Notebook and I have the following issue:

I've encrypted a folder including all subfolders using the builtin encryption feature which you get when you right-click on a folder > properties > advanced.

I moved a subfolder of this folder containing some .cpp files to an USB-Drive (FAT32) and from there on a Linux HD (EXT3/EXT4) not realizing that it was still encrypted.

On my Linux PC I obviously couldn't open those files because they had the .pfile extension and were encrypted. So I moved them back to the USB drive and from there to the notebook again.

However on the notebook now I also can't open them anymore. It seems like Win10 isn't even realizing that they're still encrypted, because that hook in the properties isn't set anymore.

I've installed using Azure Information Protection-Viewer but I only get an error that the filetype(.cpp) can't be opened. (Don't know the exact error notification in English, because I'm not on an English installation)

Comment: You need to export the original certificate that encrypted them using EFS.  I am not aware if it's possible to read encrypt files on Linux but importing the certificate on another Windows machine is of course possible.

Comment: @Ramhound I have them on the Windows Notebook with which I've encrypted them. Logged in  on the same (only) account. Shouldn't the certificate be here? I unfortunately don't know anything about the Windows encryption system.

Comment: You indicated that you encrypted the files using EFS.  When you do this a certificate was created.  You were prompted to backup this certificate or at least it was suggested.  If the machine no longer has the certificate installed then the file is lost to the encryption gods.

Comment: Yes, it said it created a certificate however I wasn't asked where I want to save it. Doesn't it save it in my account data?

Comment: It should be located in the certificate store for the user.  I can't speak to the compatibility issues that might have existed by transferring the file to EXT4 partition. The EFS in question is very much a NTFS feature.

Comment: Look in the Recycle Bin for the old versions of these files. Restore if found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears Microsoft is using previously unused fields in FAT32 directory entries and possibly also hidden directory entries and tricks with long and short filenames to store EFS metadata on FAT32:

> Encrypted files have the “.PFILE” extension and their 8.3 directory entries store additional metadata. In the current implementation, this metadata fits 6 bits: two bits are used as flags and four bits are used to store the padding size.
>
> The additional metadata is stored in the NTByte field, which is located at the offset of 12 bytes within the 8.3 directory entry. Previously, this field was only used to store two flags marking the short base name or extension as lowercase (bits #3 and #4 respectively).
>
> Now, remaining bits are used too. Bit #0 is set when the file is encrypted (it’s also set for a directory when its newly created files should be encrypted by default), bit #1 is set when the file starts with a large EFS header (otherwise, it’s a standard EFS header). Other bits (bits #2, #5, #6, and #7) are used to store the padding size (which is at most 15 bytes in size, so 4 bits are enough) – its bit #0 (LSB) goes to bit #2 of the NTByte field, bit #1 to bit #5, bit #2 to bit #6, bit #3 to bit #7.

([Source](https://dfir.ru/2021/12/08/things-you-probably-didnt-know-about-fat/), see also the referenced [US patent US10726147B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US10726147B2/en))

By moving the files away and then putting them back you have destroyed the special metadata, because Linux doesn’t know about it.

I’m sorry to say this, but your files are almost certainly beyond recovery. Still, you could try guessing the hidden metadata, there’s only 64 possible values after all. Doing this would require a raw disk hex editor or a custom filesystem driver though.

Answer (score 0):

After days of searching i found the solution,

The problem is when you copy files to Linux and copy them back the metadata for files destroyed
i solve this using Disk Editor, I've create file for the same size and encrypt it and copy it to FAT32 Drive and copy the metadata for the file after it delete it and replace it with the destroyed ".PFILE" and replace the metadata

Thank you "Daniel B" your answer was really helped me

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].