# Decrypting .PFILE files

Tags: encryption, file-corruption, efs

Long story short, while trying to convert my external SSD from exFAT to NTFS, I messed something up and ended up corrupting a folder full of EFS-encrypted files. I can see the files, but accessing them under Windows gives me an error (`Make sure a disk is in the drive you specified`). However, using Linux, I can access the files, however they are in `PFILE` format. If I try copying the `PFILE` files to Windows, it doesn't see them as encrypted and thus doesn't give the option to decrypt them. Is there any way to decrypt them, or am I screwed?

Edit: I discovered that when creating or moving an encrypted file to an exFAT drive, the file has a `PFILE` extension (visible only under Linux). However, on an NTFS drive, the file has its normal extension (under Windows and Linux). However, that shouldn't affect the decryption, since I was able to decrypt other files from the same exFAT drive successfully.

Comment: Do you mean that right-click on the file, selecting Properties, Advanced button, doesn't show the file as encrypted? Try using [Azure Information Protection Viewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54536).

Comment: If you're talking about the `PFILE` copied from Linux, then yes, the checkbox for encryption isn't checked. I also tried manually setting the attribute with [FAR](https://www.farmanager.com/), but the contents of the file are still encrypted after opening it with notepad

Comment: EFS isn’t supported on exFAT drives. You were not using Encrypted File System, through Windows on a drive with a exFAT file system. EFS only supports NTFS.

Comment: @Ramhound Weird, Windows allows me to encrypt a file I just made on the drive. And I'm sure it's actually encrypted since it contains `Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0` at the beginning.

Comment: Is it the same drive and how is it formatted now, exFAT or NTFS?

Comment: @harrymc It's the same drive and half of it (1TB) is NTFS, the other half where the encrypted files are is exFAT. I was able to move all files to the NTFS partition except this one folder.

Comment: @Ramhound: It's been supported in Windows 10 for quite a while now. They never seem to have announced it or updated the docs, but I recall it working sometime in the 19xx releases.

Comment: @u1686_grawity - What I am finding is it’s also associated with Microsoft Rights Management, which is different than EFS, but regardless the file cannot be decrypted without the certificate that was used to encrypt it. I can’t find any evidence that exFAT supports EFS. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256641/cant-open-a-windows-10-encrypted-file-transferred-to-another-pc-because-of-the) as of 2019 still suggests it wasn’t supported

Comment: @AndreiIosifescu: Azure Information Protection Viewer might be able to decrypt such files, given your user-name and password.

Comment: @Ramhound I have the certificate, just no way to use it since the files can't be opened

Comment: @harrymc Azure Information Protection Viewer requires an organizational Microsoft account. My files were encrypted from a Local account, so I don't think this is the right tool.

Comment: @Ramhound: Have you tried using it in practice to see if it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is the same as in the post
[Decrypt files moved to USB drive and back](https://superuser.com/questions/1692730/decrypt-files-moved-to-usb-drive-and-back).
That post is for FAT32, but is probably also valid for exFAT.

The answer by user Daniel B says :

> It appears Microsoft is using previously unused fields in FAT32 directory entries and possibly also hidden directory entries and tricks with long and short filenames to store EFS metadata on FAT32

With this information the poster saved his files this way:

> The problem is when you copy files to Linux and copy them back the metadata for files destroyed i solve this using Disk Editor, I've create file for the same size and encrypt it and copy it to FAT32 Drive and copy the metadata for the file after it delete it and replace it with the destroyed ".PFILE" and replace the metadata

Try to see if the same solution will work for you.
You will probably need an exFAT partition to do that in.

The trick is to copy-paste the *contents* of your PFILE
to replace those of the one in the exFAT. The file
should stay in its place inside the exFAT, not moved,
just its contents should be replaced, so that it stays
attached to its exFAT metadata (that you can't copy).

You could use for example the free
[HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)
to create and replace the file's data, as it has all
the required functionality.

Comment: The authors problem was caused by them migrating the file from exFAT to NTFS. The accepted answer seems to suggest the files are permanently lost. I don’t trust an answer with virtually no details as being possible

Comment: That guy's solution isn't clear enough, he doesen't explain how he copied and replaced the metadata. I would ask him directly but I don't have enough reputation

Comment: The other guy didn't have more info than you do now. I think that the metadata is the missing part, since you have the PFILE. I suggest to create a file of the exact size as the PFILE, encrypt it the same as you did before, then replace the data. You could try [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) to create and replace the file's data, I think it has all the required functionality.

Comment: @harrymc So I tried creating a file on an exFAT drive, encrypting it, and then copying it to Linux. However, the original file and the copied file are identical when viewed using a hex editor, so I don't know where that metadata is stored.

Comment: The trick is to copy-paste the *contents* of your PFILE to replace those of the one in the exFAT. The file should stay in its place inside the exFAT, not moved, just its contents should be replaced, so that it stays attached to its exFAT metadata (that you can't copy).

Comment: @harrymc No way, that actually worked! Thank you so much!